# A seemingly strange use of も: 「今度もきつねの言うとおりにしました」

Tags: meaning, particle-も

Take a look at this sentence:

> そこで、[山羊]{やぎ}は、[今度]{こんど}**も**きつねの[言]{い}うとおりにしました。

The ***mo*** after ***kondo*** seems strange. I know it means **also**, and it is indeed translated as so. However, there is no previous context for this **also** to make sense. More specifically, the passage does not describe a previous instance of the goat following the fox's words. So what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems difficult to judge what this 今度も is referring to without more context, so I tried searching for the sentence in question, and found what seems to be the full story [here](http://www.jpwind.com/studyol/xb/xb0310.htm).

In the first paragraph of the story, the fox asks the goat to come down to the bottom of the well, and the goat does as the fox says. Then the fox asks the goat to stand in a specific position, and that's when we get this sentence saying "And so, the goat once again did as the fox said." So it is indeed the second time the goat is following the fox's instructions.

Comment: I get what you mean. It seems that I kind of misinterpreted the passage. Anyway, thanks so much!